# What does Partition (CI) / Partition (STL) in PLSQL mean?

Tags: sql, oracle

What does this partition (CI) mean? I found a similar join which has Partition (STL).

```sql
select *
from   SMPRECON_FACT f
       LEFT JOIN SMP_FACT PARTITION (CI) j
       on (f.POS_NBR = j.POS_NBR AND f.PO_ITEM_ID = j.PO_ITEM_ID)
```

Comment: Look at "partition_extension_clause":  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__GUID-AA6B72FA-DDAA-42CD-A8B0-D0DC9C9A65B7

Comment: And https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__GUID-6927FCA1-1ADA-4099-91BD-0F7A9494294F

Comment: Thanks Sayan. As per this, it looks like CI and STL are columns in the table, but I don't see them in schema browser. Could it be because of a hidden field or something? I only have read only access

Comment: No, those are partitions. Read about partitioned tables. You can find them in `all_tab_partitions`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/vldbg/partition-concepts.html